# How do I make the R kernel available to jupyter?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I have read multiple articles along this line, but they all use conda to install R.  I am not using conda; I have Windows Subsystem for Linux installed.  I was successfully able to install Python, create a virtual environment, and install and run jupyter notebook in that virtual environment.

I installed R in WSL, then activated my virtual environment and ran R with "sudo R" because I was getting a permissions issue.  I was able to install IRkernel, but I get an error when I run this:

```
IRkernel::installspec(user=FALSE)
```

The error message is: "jupyter-client has to be installed but 'jupyter kernelspec --version' exited with code 127".

I thought it might be a path error, so I used this:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH="everything from getenv:/path-to-virtual-env/bin")
```

Tried using installspec again but got the same 127 error.

I'm concerned that it might be because of where I put my virtual environment.  To access your files on Windows from within WSL, you have to go to "/mnt/c/Users/your-username/".  That's where my virtual environment is, and I'm wondering if that's why R can't see it even when I explicitly tell R where it is.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue under Ubuntu. It may be because R can't access the jupyter command even though you start it in the virtualenv. I would also like to find out how to fix this.